# CUBESET with Slicer

Tags: excel, excel-formula, mdx, cube, excel-2016

I wish to show the top 10 people who send emails to a mailbox, within a date range (chosen by slicer). The below code works for the entirety of the dataset, but I can't seem to find an example to work with a slicer. But I've got it to work with one slicer value.

```
=CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel"
    ,"TOPCOUNT(
                [MSExchange].[Sender.Name].children
                ,10
                ,SUM([Measures].[Count Inbound mail],[Calendar].[YYYY-MM].&["&D5&"]))"
               )"
    ,"Top 10"
    ,2
    ,"[Measures].[Count Inbound mail]"
)

--D5 == CUBERANKEDMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel",Slicer_YYYY_MM,1)
```

I believe the "Exists" keyword may be used with two expressions but I've had no luck with that so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [slicers](https://support.office.com/article/use-slicers-to-filter-data-249f966b-a9d5-4b0f-b31a-12651785d29d) to filter **[table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/table-e81aa349-b006-4f8a-9806-5af9df0ac664)** data, or **[PivotTable](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pivottable-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)** data.

The first step is to get your data into table form (or into a PivotTable) and then you can apply a slicer.

---

### More Information:

- Chris Webb : [**Using CubeSet() to Combine Selections From Multiple Slicers**](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/09/14/using-the-cubeset-function-to-combine-selections-from-multiple-slicers-in-excel-power-pivot-reports/)
- Office.com : [**Use slicers to filter data**](https://support.office.com/article/use-slicers-to-filter-data-249f966b-a9d5-4b0f-b31a-12651785d29d)
- PowertPivotPro: [**Using Slicers to Filter a CUBESET**](https://forum.powerpivotpro.com/forums/topic/using-slicers-to-filter-a-cubeset/)
- PowerPivotPro : [**Tricks to Make Your Cube Formula Scorecards Drama-Free!**](https://powerpivotpro.com/2015/09/two-tricks-to-make-your-cube-formula-scorecards-drama-free/)
- Stack Overflow : [**Excel Filter a CUBESET with Slicers**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44643175/8112776)

Comment: Slicers can also be applied to CubeValues() which are neither a table or a PivotTable. As PPP & SO links point out CubeSet() can be used to create a tuple from slicer selections, and then passed as a filter but I have not come across this method used to populate another CubeSet(). That is the requirement I see to find the top 10(n) over a period. I appreciate the links but I'd already gone through all but one of them prior to posting the question. This answer does not seem to answer the question, rather just link to related sites as a bot would.

Comment: I've updated my question as the CubeSet() is now filtering with the first value of a slicer.